# HTCondor: "Process: not found [No such file or directory]" when passing $(Process) as an arguments to executable

Tags: condor

so I have an executable file `fit` that I want to run with HTCondor. The executable takes an integer 0 <= i <= 9 as argument. I would like to associate i to be the job process number: $(Process). So I have a submit file such that:

```
   executable              = /nfs/...script_test.sh
   arguments               = $(Process)
   log                     = fit.$(Process).log
   output                  = outfile_fit.$(Process).txt
   error                   = errors_fit.$(Process).txt
   transfer_input_files    = /nfs/...
   should_transfer_files   = Yes
   when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT
   queue 10
```

My shell script is simply:

```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/nfs/...:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"  
   ./fit $(Process)
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
  Failed to find a valid KRB5 credential cache. Aborting.
  Failed to find a valid KRB5 credential cache. Aborting.
  aklog: All mechanisms failed to produce tokens for cell desy.de
  /var/lib/condor/execute/dir_20552/condor_exec.exe[3]: Process: not found [No such file or   directory]
  /var/lib/condor/execute/dir_20552/condor_exec.exe: line 3: 26653: Memory fault
```

If I set $(Process) to a given integer, the job is running well but I still get the errors

```
Failed to find a valid KRB5 credential cache. Aborting.
Failed to find a valid KRB5 credential cache. Aborting.
aklog: All mechanisms failed to produce tokens for cell desy.de
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the first line of your shell script with

#!/bin/sh

and instead of

./fit $(process)

try

./fit $1